# ZendeskSDK integration via cocoapods and Xcode 10.2 says Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0 compiler

Tags: ios, swift4.2, zendesk, swift5, xcode10.2

I just updated the Xcode 10.1 to Xcode 10.2 and after that when i try to build my app i found an error says. **Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0 compiler.**

```
/myProjectFolderPath/myProjectName/ViewControllers/FeedbackVC/SupportViewController.swift:11:8: Module compiled with Swift 4.2 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.0 compiler: /myProjectFolderPath/Pods/ZendeskSDK/ZendeskSDK/4.2.1/ZendeskSDK.framework/Modules/ZendeskSDK.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule
```

Issue is with ZendeskSDK which i integrated via cocoapods.

Need help and thanks in advance.